# Removing the Google Maps API Premier Terms-of-Use/Logo/etc. links?

Tags: javascript, css, api, google-maps

is it legal to remove the logo/terms of use link displayed on my integrated google map (google maps premier)? The problem is that when I zoom into the map, the link tends to get longer and loger and overlays the whole website which is pretty ugly. Of course it is possible to give the div container a "overflow: hidden;" flag which helps a little. But it is still not satisfying.

Thx

Answer (score 17):

If you use the Google Maps service in any way, they request that you retain their branding. It is infact in the Terms of Service I believe, so techincally no it is not legal.

> 9.4 Attribution Content provided to you through the Service may contain the trade names, trademarks, service marks, logos, domain names, and other distinctive brand features of Google, its partners, or other third party rights holders of content indexed by Google. **You may not delete or in any manner alter these trade names, trademarks, service marks, logos, domain names, and other distinctive brand features.**

Reference: http://code.google.com/apis/maps/terms.html

While it is against the Terms of Service, this is however possible using CSS rules - however the below reference is using a GreaseMonkey script. It may be possible with an included Stylesheet.

Reference: http://userstyles.org/styles/1929

Comment: Then, why UBER and other apps they hide "terms and conditions" located inside Google Maps ?

Comment: @Ivan they are.

Answer (score 16):

You can remove it as long as you put the data next to the map on your page.

From Google's Permissions page:

http://www.google.com/permissions/geoguidelines.html

> **All uses of Google Maps and Google Earth and Content MUST provide
>   attribution to Google and our
>   suppliers. In no circumstance do we
>   approve of any use of Content without
>   proper attribution. Requests for
>   exceptions will not be answered.**
>
> Attribution is the line(s) shown on
>   the bottom of the Content in the
>   products along with copyright notices,
>   such as "© 2009 Google, Map Data ©
>   2009 Tele Atlas." (The exact text of
>   the attribution changes based on
>   geography and Content type.) The
>   attribution text must be legible to
>   the average viewer or reader. The
>   automatically-generated Google logo
>   and attribution text may only be
>   removed or obstructed if reintroduced
>   in a visible form elsewhere within the
>   Content. In print use, if for some
>   reason attribution cannot be placed
>   within the Content, separate
>   attribution text must be provided
>   directly adjacent to the Content. In
>   video, attribution must appear
>   on-screen for the entire duration the
>   Content is displayed; we cannot
>   approve requests to move attribution
>   to end credits. Below is a
>   demonstration on where to find
>   attribution in Earth and Maps.

Answer (score 12):

Without using any javascript or so, with pure CSS rules, there is a method to hide the google footer image and copyright from the map.

Pay Attention, it's for research purpose only, because it's not Legal, these are the CSS rules:

```
/*======= Map Styling ============*/
.gmnoprint a, .gmnoprint span {
    display:none;
}
.gmnoprint div {
    background:none !important;
}
#GMapsID div div a div img{
    display:none;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

This CSS works like charm. Removes *Google Logo* as well as *terms of use*.

```
a[href^="http://maps.google.com/maps"]{display:none !important}

.gmnoprint a, .gmnoprint span {
    display:none;
}
.gmnoprint div {
    background:none !important;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

By using Styled Maps by Google, the logo and terms of use link are by default small and unintrusive. I have experience using this in a mobile web app where a larger Google icon would hinder the use of the map, and it works like a charm.

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/styling?csw=1

Answer (score 0):

http://support.google.com/enterprise/doc/gme/terms/maps_purchase_agreement.html

> **3.3 Linking to Maps Terms**. If Customer is using a Javascript API or Maps API
>   for Flash to receive the Content, a
>   link to the Maps Terms is provided on
>   the Content.  If Customer is using a
>   static Maps API to receive the
>   Content, Customer will incorporate a
>   link to the Maps Terms and the Legal
>   Notices in a license agreement
>   governing End Users' use of the
>   Customer Implementation.

Answer (score 0):

I used below css code to hide text and google logo

```
.gmnoprint {
    display: none;
}
.gm-style > div > div > a > div > img {
    display: none;
}
```

[image]

Answer (score -1):

simply code css for logo

```
img[src=http://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/api-3/images/google_white2.png]
{display:none}
```

Comment: actually this is generally a working formula, 
=> 1. inspect the item you want to hide, (get the element and a unique attribute, like img[aria-label="Google"])
=> 2. set it to `display: none !important;`