# How to remove google maps company infos?

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I will use google maps for my project. As the overlay I will use a map, with streets.

The problem is, that google has placed on this overlay a lot of things that I don't need.

How company's and some way info, and at the end it is not only painted, it is click-able, so that it creates info window with details of this point and URL if exist.

This is what I do not need. How can I remove it with Google Maps API?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Removing the Google Maps API Premier Terms-of-Use/Logo/etc. links?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2553904/removing-the-google-maps-api-premier-terms-of-use-logo-etc-links)

Comment: No, with trade marks, i have no problems, i respect this rule =)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Are you talking about removing the labels of various objects from the map?  If so, then you need to use a map styles array, and then set the visibility of the particular object to off.  So for example, this:

```
var styleArray = [
   {
    featureType: "poi.business",
    elementType: "labels",
    stylers: [
      { visibility: "off" }
    ]
  }
];
```

will turn business labels off so that you don't see them, nor will they be clickable any more.  You would create the object as shown above, then set this object to the "styles" property of your map options object before finally giving it to your map:

```
  myOptions = {
          center: new google.maps.LatLng(38.955, -94.806),
          zoom: 13,
          minZoom:13,
          maxZoom:23,
          scaleControl:true,
          styles: styleArray,
          mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
            };
        }

        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"),
            myOptions);
```

Comment: Thank you, that was what i need. I have only one quastion about JS write style. I have write my options like this way: ` way_map = new google.maps.Map(
  document.getElementById("map_main"),{
   draggable:true,
   overviewMapControlOptions:{
    opened:false
    },
   zoom:14,
   zoomControl:true,
   zoomControlOptions:{
    position:google.maps.ControlPosition.RIGHT_CENTER,
    style:google.maps.ZoomControlStyle.LARGE
    }});` Also anytime, where i needed a array of options, i have use a simply `{,,,}` why do i need to use in this case `[{,,}]`?